# How to encrypt HTML+JS assets in Android Phonegap mobile app?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cordova, obfuscation

I have mobile app created using Phonegap basic wrapper and HTML5. My goal is to encrypt files in assets directory (JS and HTML files) so they are unreadable to people, who unzip the APK file and want to see the JS sources.

Ok, i know there is no absolute perfect solution. On my way to this question I've already tried options how to solve copy protection of my sources (JS minification, obfuscation, etc..), but I found out that it's very simple to get to the original code (using JSBeautifier, firebug, including obfuscated scripts, etc...).

So my question is - is there some simple way how to encrypt JS+HTML files (so they are not readable and useful when simply unzipping APK file) and how to implement it in JAVA for Android platform ?

**Note:** I have no knowledge of JAVA language, so please include working example which I can use.

**Edit:** I also investigated ProGuard feature when making final APK package, however it is useless for me, because it only deals with JAVA files, but leaves assets directory as it is.

Comment: As for "changing approach" suggestions - I have no other choice. I've created mobile app using Phonegap because I didn't have time to learn JAVA. So I can't change my approach, because the app is already completed in HTML+JS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some time ago I have same problem but on iOS. And the result was only after patching PhoneGap for iOS. I have wrote an article at http://oleksiy.pro/2011/09/20/phonegap-application-encryption/. Also, for Android this method could be weak, because java code could be 99% decompiled, and hacker will see your key.

Comment: ioleksiy: Your patch looks promising. Do you think you could find similar solution for Android ?

Comment: As I said, Android platform is writtent with a help of Java. So, if you even create such patch for Android PhoneGap, you will need to obfuscate the result classes, so nobody will decompile the code and view your key.

Comment: This isn't just weak on Android, it's weak on any device. If someone cares, they'll see the code. (Fortunately the truth of the matter is that in 99% of the cases, nobody cares about your silly code — who wants to maintain somebody else's undecipherable code? If they want your app's functionality they'll just copy the binary.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to do this. If you want to encrypt your JavaScript you would need some sort of key to decrypt it with. The key cannot be stored on the device since then it's easy to find the key and decrypt the source code. Iff your application requires a user to login you could possibly return the encryption key once the user is logged in and use that key to decrypt JS and HTML files. There are standard Android encryption libraries that you can use via a PhoneGap plugin.

Having said that, it's just JavaScript so if there is something that you really need to have encrypted you should probably consider changing your approach.

Comment: Can you please supply me with some links about those PhoneGap plugins you are talking about ? I can't find anything which could be easily used..

Comment: @Frodik Did you end up finding something for this?

Answer (score 4):

The best combination I've found is the [DojoToolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org) and the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode.

Closure in Advanced Mode makes JavaScript code almost impossible to reverse-engineer, even after passing through a beautifier.  Once your JavaScript code is obfuscated beyond any recognition and any possibility to reverse-engineer, your HTML won't disclose much of your secrets.

This link for using the Dojo Toolkit with the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode for mobile applications:

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t

And of course the Dojo Toolkit works well with PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webview and load a base64 string:

```
protected String base64Str = "+wL00h2L....";
wv1.loadData(base64Str, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```

Comment: Can you please explain more on this?? How can we get customized (decrypting the encrypted data) in cordova android application?? How can we customize WebResourceResponse?? OR how can we use shouldInterceptRequest() in cordova based hybrid application??