# ProGuard obfuscation on Eclipse Android project (Phonegap app)

Tags: android, cordova, proguard, obfuscation, cordova-plugin-proguard

I make some Phonegap Android apps on Eclipse, but I need to obfuscate the "assets" folder or the content of this, How I can make it?? Maybe configuring proguard.cfg file???

I need to make some obfuscation like the other files, because if you decompile the APK file on Apk Manager can see the "assets" folder withous obfuscation and can access to html files or others.

Anybody can help with that?
I read a lot about ProGuard but I can't understand If I can also obfuscate other files..

Sorry for my bad english :P

Thanks!

¡Gracias!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt HTML+JS assets in Android Phonegap mobile app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160554/how-to-encrypt-htmljs-assets-in-android-phonegap-mobile-app)

Comment: @fretje that wouldnot work for android.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard is for obfuscating code. Your best bet is to encrypt and archive your assets separately, and then retrieve them after the app is installed.

Comment: @Glitch can you explain a bit ?