# Is it possible to encrypt/decrypt an SQLite database using only Javascript?

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, encryption

I'm making an iOS application using html5, phonegap (cordova), and SQLite (to manage my data). Is it possible to encrypt the SQLite database or its data, then decrypt it using only Javascript? Is there another way to secure my application data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to encrypt your data, but since Phonegap's application source is always visible to user, the user will always see the way how to decrypt the Sqlite database.

I was researching on this issue a while ago and here is my question with some information below: [How to encrypt HTML+JS assets in Android Phonegap mobile app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160554/how-to-encrypt-htmljs-assets-in-android-phonegap-mobile-app)

The best I have come up with so far is using JScrambler.com which can obfuscate your JS code so it will hide from the user your encryption technique. However it is not safe nor bullet-proof. Advanced users will be always able to turn your JS code to something they can read. It just helps to avoid script-kiddies and novices...