# How can I obfuscate javascript and html file using phonegap and android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have a phonegap app and I want to launch it to Google play Market.
Before launch, I want to encrypt/obfuscate my code.
Please suggest me the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to encrypt/obfuscate code for Phonegap is to actually have the native compiled code do the encrypting/decrypting.

You can find more information on how to do it here: http://www.oleksiy.pro/2011/09/20/phonegap-application-encryption/

**Edit**:  This only works for iOS based compiles.  Another similar question can be found here:
[How to encrypt HTML+JS assets in Android Phonegap mobile app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160554/how-to-encrypt-htmljs-assets-in-android-phonegap-mobile-app)

If you just need a generic obfuscator YUI compressor works well. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Comment: ok thanks, BTW, YUI compressor is only used to combined the code and it changes variable names and function parameters. But that is not obfuscation. We need converted code should not be in readable form and any one should not able to pick out the logic that we have developed.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little out of left field but one of the best ways to obfuscate your application's inner workings would be to migrate some/all of the business logic to a server-side web-service.

Comment: If our application is only client side so what may be the solution.

Comment: Ah, well that's that then! For future projects though I would highly recommend having a server component though, it makes it exceedingly difficult to duplicate the service and you could expand your feature set too (syncing across devices for example). Best of luck Neel!