# Source of html files , phonegap

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, payload

I made an app in phonegap ( xcode ) . all of my codes and files are in www folder in application's payload folder. user can access all of them , is there any way to restrict access of www folder or encrypt files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Other people have solved this problem on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160554/how-to-encrypt-htmljs-assets-in-android-phonegap-mobile-app), and one of the answers points to this tutorial that might have a good hint for iOS:

http://www.oleksiy.pro/2011/09/20/phonegap-application-encryption/