# Securing an API without Login Based Authentication

Tags: ios, security, laravel

I have an API that needs to be accessed by mobile devices (iOS). The distribution of the mobile app will be controlled to only those who are supposed to have access to the data, but anyone could access the API through their browser. I want to restrict access to only those with the mobile app.

Would it be secure to have a key hardcoded into the app that would be sent with each request (https of course)? If the app were to fall into the wrong hands, could it easily be disassembled and the key discovered?

What would be the best way to ensure that only mobile users have access to this API?

Comment: Users should be authenticated `IMO`.

Comment: I agree, however the managers in charge of the project would prefer to not require authentication. Additionally, if I wanted to enable username/password auth, I would have to bind the credentials with a LDAP server increasing complexity, but still relatively straightforward.

Comment: How the users will get the app ? Is that possible to generate some unique identifier/token during the download/installation of the app automatically and tracking that token when request is made to the server?

Comment: Distribution will be through something like mobileiron. I don't think they offer any such ability to generate a token on install and send that to the server, but I'll check the docs. I could make a request to get a UID when the user launches the app for the first time, but if it leaked outside the mobileiron platform, the data would be compromised.

Comment: You may use `SSL/HTTPS`.

Comment: So hardcoding a key into the app and transmitting it only via an HTTPS request would be sufficient to prevent someone from gaining access to the key? My concern is if the app is leaked and decompiled, the key could be discovered and also I would have no way of tracking individual devices. I think I will just make the app do an initial request on first launch to get an UID and then just use access tokens to manage auth. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By de-compiling the app anyone can get that. Secure request only secures the transmit.

Comment: Exactly. It looks like I'll have to compromise on that point. I must then assume that we can control the distribution of the app. Thanks.

Comment: This may also be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21578907/1836314

Comment: Thanks for the link. It basically states that I must necessarily introduce a security hole with having no authentication, in the event that the app is distributed to unauthorized persons accidentally or otherwise. Obfuscation of Objective C doesn't seem reasonable.