# Separating js files that do calculations into another file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am building a Visual Studio 2015 Cordova app.  Within this app I have 4 js files which provide all the calculations that make this app work.
I would like to separate these files out and just reference them like you would a dll.
I also heard that in a Cordova app all js files are rendered as plain text which would reveal the calculation structure that what makes the app work.
Basically I want to protect these files from easy viewing.
Since I'm working in Javascript and on mobile devices I'm not sure of the best way to implement this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating the files doesn't do much, in fact, combining them and [obfuscate](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) the code would be the simplest approach.

Better but more involved, you can employ some kind of encryption that will make it more difficult to reverse engineer. A good article can be found [here](http://oleksiy.pro/2011/09/20/phonegap-application-encryption/) in response to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160554/how-to-encrypt-htmljs-assets-in-android-phonegap-mobile-app). It's a bit involved to post the exact code here and it's geared toward an OS X development environment, but I'm sure it can be adapted.

Essentially you encrypt the source files (PHP but could be done with any language) using a key like `ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`:

```
<?
function icrypt($plaintext, $key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}
//usage:
$newHtml = icrypt('<html>Source File</html>', 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff');
```

Then have your app decrypt the source files in memory (which requires some changes to PhoneGap/Cordova), using a method like this (truncated for clarity):

```
- (void) fetchKey:(char[]) key
{
    //ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
    key[0] = 0x66;
    key[1] = 0x66;
    key[2] = 0x66;
    key[3] = 0x66;
    key[4] = 0x66;
    key[5] = 0x66;
    key[6] = 0x66;
    key[7] = 0x66;
    key[8] = 0x66;
    key[9] = 0x66;
...
```

The articles do a much better job showing the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider putting this sensitive code in a web service, and call it from the mobile app.  You can secure the web service code by using a compiled language (like c#, c++, java, etc), or if you want to keep your current work in javascript, convert it to use as a nodejs module to respond as a web service.